# How to get all the objects in a table where the coordinates intersects with polygon with SQL Spatial Data

Tags: sql, geospatial, mysql-spatial

I have an SQL table which called `DATAB` which contains thousands of objects ordered by the following colunms:
`[id] [angel] [latitude] [longitude]`

And i have this polygon set with `STPolyFromText`:

```
DECLARE @polygon geography;
SET @polygon = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((35.22272601642959 32.78460617177918, 35.08671584135056 32.78345098011482, 35.11007112393986 32.873510861418836, 35.213109135363425 32.86716347866004, 35.22272601642959 32.78460617177918))', 4326);
```

Now i want to make a `SELECT` query that returns all the rows where the waypoints (consisting of the `longitude` and `latitude` variables that are in each row) are on the border of the polygon or within the area of the polygon.

Be aware that the variables `latitude` and `longitude` that are in each row are just numbers, not geography objects.

I tried to do somthing like this:

```
DECLARE @f geography;
SELECT * FROM DATAB
WHERE (SET @f = geography::STPointFromText('POINT('[longitude]' '[latitude]')', 4326)) ON (@g.STIntersects(@f) = 1)
```

Obviously, it failed.

Any ideas?